# Chrome AJAX on page-load causes "busy cursor" to remain

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome, loading

In Google Chrome, AJAX called within $(function(){....}); seems to keep the page loading.

I have a site with a few pages with tabs. Because I'm using cheap godaddy hosting, I want the page to load as fast as possible. I thus want to load a page on 1 tab and then in the background use AJAX to load the other tabs. When I run AJAX from

```
$(function(){
    /*AJAX CODE HERE */
});
```

The cursor shows the page as loading for a long time (http://jsfiddle.net/mazlix/7fDYE/9/)

I have figured out a way (in chrome atleast) to somewhat fix that using `setTimeout();` (http://jsfiddle.net/mazlix/7fDYE/8/), but this only works if you correctly predict when the window finishes fully loading and obviously makes it take longer to load. I want a way to load content via AJAX immediately after the page loads, so no "busy-cursor" is displayed while waiting for the returned AJAX.

Comment: is there another kind? look at my jsfiddles for the code.. if i'm doing the AJAX calls wrong though I don't know why stuff shows up..

Comment: FWIW it works fine in FF4 and IE9. If the `setTimeout` trick takes care of it in Chrome then I'd say go for it. I'm not sure why Chrome chooses that behavior: e.g. is it intentional or a side-effect? (AJAX/XHR can be run synchronously, but it is not in that example.)

Comment: Please retest my answer below, with window.load instead of document ready.  I believe it works now.

Comment: I don't see any issue with the cursor in chrome, take a look at my jsFiddle for it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Google Chrome shows Loading Indicator as long as there are no new queries to servers. While the loading indicator is shown, all new requests are causing Chrome to extend the time the indicator is shown. Furthermore, when `esc` is pressed while the indicator is shown, all requests are aborted! These include AJAX requests and even Flash requests! Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6015496/how-does-youtube-control-flash-content-loading-chrome-12): i thought it was because of Youtube, but it turned to be Chrome's usual behavior.

The only way to avoid "extending" the time Loading indicator is shown, is making the requests **after the loading indicator is hidden**: i.e. when all queries to server are completed. [JQuery's documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) on `.load()` says:

> The load event is sent to an element when it and all sub-elements have been completely loaded. This event can be sent to any element associated with a URL: images, scripts, frames, iframes, and the window object.

So, if you're sure that there are only images, scripts and frames on your page, `window.load()` will be fired just when you need it. Adding `setTimeout()` to it will work as you like. Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/7fDYE/22/

If there are other requests being made **before your request**, you should wait for them to be completed! For example, you know that besides the images/scripts etc. you have 3 more AJAX requests before the page loads. You can have something like this:

```
var loaded=0,needsToBeLoaded=4; //3 AJAX + window
function onLoad(){
    loaded++;
    if(loaded==needsToBeLoaded){
         //do the AJAX request   
    }
}
window.load(onLoad);
// add onLoad() to all 3 AJAX request handlers
```

I'm not sure what you can do with Flash requests...

Comment: Good idea with the waiting for all requests to trigger load. That should do the trick.

Comment: you can subscribe for special event `ajaxStop` and put your ajax request in its handler and then unsubscribe in order not to be executed again

Answer (score 3):

#### Update

This solution will not work for Chrome. It stops the loading indicator only when all requests made before window load have completed. The only solution appears to be to get it to make the request after window load, but as far as I know, this is only possible with setTimeout, which isn't great.

---

#### Update

To get around the pointer issue in Chrome, you could set the cursor style as shown in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7fDYE/19/). It's a bit hacky and it doesn't address the issue of the loading indicator at the top of the tab.

---

The loading indicator will be present in browsers until the page has loaded (window's load event). In `$(function(){someCode();});`, `someCode` is executed when the DOM load event is triggered (when all content has been parsed and inserted into the DOM, before page load). The execution of JavaScript at this point blocks the window's load event from firing, and so prevents the loading indicator from stopping. Note that image loading also blocks the window's load event.

Instead, you could try `$(window).load(function(){someCode();});`. In this example, `someCode` is executed when the window's load event is triggered. This is at the point where the browser's loading indicator stops.

So, instead of:

```
$(function(){
    /*AJAX CODE HERE */
});
```

Try:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    /*AJAX CODE HERE */
});
```

Note that this may cause your JavaScript to begin execution later, which may not be desirable.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, that does not work either, see how when using chrome the favicon and busy-cursor remain loading until the AJAX is finished. http://jsfiddle.net/mazlix/7fDYE/12/

Comment: Sorry, it looks like Chrome doesn't stop the loading indicator until all JavaScript that began execution before the window load event finished bubbling has finished. So, if your script starts when window load occurs, it will block the loading indicator because window load hasn't finished when the script starts. Other browsers behave sensibly. It looks like the only way around this is with setTimeout (like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ugTLz/3/)). It's not a great solution though... It will be hard to predict when the window load event will have finished and will mean content is loaded later.

Comment: is this a knwon chrome issue? or do they not consider it a bug? is there some other trick you can think of like body.hover() [except i assume that won't work for mobile devices]

Comment: I think it is intended behaviour (because the page hasn't actually finished loading). The only workaround I can think of is setTimeout and that won't be very good. I thought you might be able to listen for the focus event of the first element to be focused on the page, but that can happen before window load. I would just go with the window load event and admit defeat for Chrome.

Comment: I put up a bounty to try and encourage a solution, I really would like to have the AJAX not cause the "busy-cursor"

Comment: If it's just the cursor you care about (as opposed to the loading indicator at the top of the tab), you could set the cursor style. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7fDYE/19/) (based on your original) for a working example. You may want to set it to something other than 'pointer'. You can't use 'default' though, because at that point, the default cursor is a loading indicator... You could set it to a custom pointer if you want.

Answer (score 3):

There is a super simple, fool proof solution to this:

Wrap your function in a setTimeout call, and use an interval of 0.  This will queue the function to be called immediately, but Chrome will no longer wait for it to load before considering the page 'complete'.   You do NOT need to make any guesses about when the page will be complete, just make sure you're calling setTimeout inside the jquery Ready handler, like so:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#result").html(ajax_load);
        $.post("/echo/json/", {json: json1, delay: 10000}, show_json, "json");
    }, 0);
});
```

Comment: this won't work! Take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/7fDYE/20/ I've added a `<img>` with relatively large image file. Browser's loading indicator won't stop until the image is loaded. But `$(function(){ ... })` will work before that, AJAX will be called **before** page loading completes and Chrome will wait for AJAX call to be completed

Comment: You're correct, my mistake.  You have to attach to the window.load actually, not document ready.  I've edited to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

According to JQuery docs, no javascript should be run till ready for example

```
$(document).ready(function() {someCode();});
```

with that in mind i changed your [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gVjyj/)  (it takes some time to load but it works)

Edit: hadnt forked jsfiddle ><

Comment: you say it takes some time to load, but its not loading.. it's done "loading" its just "waiting". If I hit ESC during your example the information never comes, but look at the examples with setTimeout, they don't have this problem

Comment: I'm on chrome version 12.0.742.100 and it is working fine it waits for exactly the delay time (change delay to `delay: 0` for instant callback), what version are you testing with?

Comment: but it shouldn't wait for the delay time. look at the other example, in that one the cursor finishes once all things are loaded.. as it waits for the callback http://jsfiddle.net/7fDYE/22/ , in this example chromes behavior is the same as firefox/i.e.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I agree that this is a problem. I'd say this is a desirable behavior from chrome as it indicates that it's in fact not finished loading. I would say that Firefox is actually incorrect about not indicating that it's still waiting for a script callback to finish.

This could be a matter of personal taste (I like the browser to indicate that it's waiting/working, even if it makes my browser seem slow), in which case succeeding in "fixing" this "problem", will make the browser not behave in the way the user is used to. In web development you really should not try to force the browser to behave in a specific way that is not essential to how the webapp works, because you're likely to end up enforcing a look-and-feel from one os you're used to into another os with a different feel, making it feel more foreign to the users of another os (even if it makes the site feel more native to you).

The busy cursor is not a problem anyway, because elements already loaded, are still responsive.

Comment: I would agree, however a lot of users will be 'happier' if it _seems_ as though the page has finished loading sooner. I'm not saying that it's a good idea though.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is a Chrome issue and they are not fixing it:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=26723

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/24001218)

Comment: @ReeganMiranda This looks like it could well be a useful answer. Please check out [when to delete in LQP](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue)