# jQuery ajax php long polling

Tags: php, jquery, long-polling, server-push

I've been trying to get this long polling script to work but I keep getting stuck. This time I have a problem with the ajax request to the server. The php script that serves the data (running the long-poll using a loop and sleep) works perfectly fine but my jQuery script doesn't.

So far I've tried using a normal `$.ajax()` request and a `$.post()` request to the script however when I do so the entire script stalls. Well the script actually loads like it is supposed to but the page shows that it keeps loading (using google chrome it shows the "waiting for" bar at the bottom of the screen). After the 60 second timeout in the php script the jQuery script receives "false" because no data was found. The script is then supposed to ask for the data agian.

My question is: how do I avoid the browser showing that it's loading something in the background? My server is a shared server so I don't have access when it comes to installing stuff on the server itself so this have to be solved using only javascript (jQuery) and php.

EDIT: just checked my script out in Internet Explorer and it doesn't seem to be showing any signs that the script is loading but it's still a problem in Google Chrome

**EDIT** Posting some code:

This is my javascript file:

```
if($("#interestboard"))
{
    var lasttime = $("#lasttime").val();
    var pollurl = $("#pollurl").val();
    lpStart();
}
function lpStart()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: pollurl+lasttime,
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        success:function(data)
        {
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function()
        {
            alert("Something went wrong");
        }
    });
}
```

Of course this is wrapped within the `$(document).ready()`

My php script is something like the following:

```
while(time()-$time<60)
    {
        $this->class = $class["id"];
        $this->orderBy("timestamp");
        $this->_extraConditions = "`timestamp`>'$lastTime' AND ";
        $result = $this->search();
        if($result)
            return $result;
        usleep(250000);
        clearstatcache();
    }
```

When using firebug (with Google Chrome) it only shows that a request has been made but not showing the usual loading-icon at the end of the GET string in the console. In Firefox it also just shows that a request is pending (showing the loading icon) but at least the browser doesn't act like the page is loading.

Thanks...

Comment: Are you using Firefox and firebug? That will help tell you whats going on. Could you post some code?

Comment: Just edited the original post so that it contains the source code and a brief description of the result of using Firebug

Comment: I got part of it working now. If I set a timeout to invoke the lpStart() function two seconds AFTER DOM has loaded Google Chrome won't show the loading-bar however this presents a new problem. Whenever I stop the request (i.e. by clicking a link) the error event is fired and I get an alert telling me that "Something went wrong" (like it's supposed to). After this that site won't load until the request timout time has been reached.. This only happens if I'm in the same browser (same session) - not when I get the error on my computer and then load the page on my iPad...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should read top comment on [Chrome AJAX on page-load causes "busy cursor" to remain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6287736/chrome-ajax-on-page-load-causes-busy-cursor-to-remain) - it seems it is Google Chrome specific and you need to wait before *ALL* content is loaded before making an ajax call.

EDIT: Just a recommendation - maby I am wrong: you should not use GET requests to make any huge/sensitive operations on your site as it can lead to and easy attack on your site. Anyone who owns/hacks some high-load site can insert an invisible iframe to their page so that any user that visits that page will make that GET request without even realising it - it can crash/harm your server (as thousands requests comes to your server). Most modern browsers will not let cross-site POST requests, so it should be safe.

EDIT 2: About your site being unavaliable while that script is still working even after you abort it: it is most likely because of sessions. Standard session behaviour will let only one php instance with same session running at the same moment - all other requests will wait untill that session is closed in all other scripts. You should [close the session](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.session-write-close.php) ASAP in script, use custom session handling that will enable multiple requests with the same session(most likely this will be really ugly) or [detect user abort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.connection-aborted.php) to close the sript as soon as user aborted it in browser.

Comment: I've tried detecting the user abort before but I read something somewhere about the session storage directory permissions that will not allow the php script to detect user abort when it's an ajax call to the script.. The only thing is I haven't changed the default session storage directory.. Do you know how I can detect the user abort in php when it's an ajax call?

Comment: I got it working now.. A combination of the two things you mentioned. I added `session_write_close();` just before the while-loop and then added `if(connection_aborted) break;` to the end of my while-loop. This way it detects the abortion of the script and everything works as it's supposed to :-)

Comment: I'm glad I could help. But you got that information about AJAX call wrong: web server can't detect if user is using AJAX call or just a page request(well sometimes it can, but not very reliable): they are both simple HTTP requests (you can even look at requests in firebug and compare them). AJAX is not some new technology - it was used for ages (using iframes), the only new thing we got with XMLHttpRequest object(or analogs) is better control over what is going on in this request.