# jQuery Instant Notifications

Tags: php, jquery, long-polling

I am creating a web application, and I am in need of some way to do the following in jQuery and PHP:

- jQuery sends a request to a PHP page
- PHP page checks if there is anything new, if not, stalls the jQuery request until there is
- jQuery gets the response and sends another request, repeating the process

I have tried Long-polling methods on Google with jQuery but they pretty much do the same. This is the sort of thing I'm looking for.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What you described *is* long-polling, what's wrong with doing that?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6433356/jquery-ajax-php-long-polling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as a precursor, if you do go down that route, you should also make sure that your sessions are not locked per request. You could easily hit a situation when a session gets locked when you make the request.

As a better option, you might want to just work on a "heartbeat" like solution, by requesting the PHP page every 30 seconds. (which is similar to what StackOverflow) do hear to notify you when a new message has come in.

*Even better* than that, would be to use WebSockets in node.js. You could even have PHP notify node.js when something "new" comes in, like you say, so that it is always accurate, and you don't have some PHP script constantly running.

WebSockets via [socket.io](http://socket.io)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a settimeout in JS that starts over every time PHP returns no updates?

So:

- Call JS function that checks PHP via Ajax (`checkPHP()`).
- PHP sees no new values, returns '0' for instance
- In the data receive function for the AJAX function, check the return, if return value == 0: `settimeout(checkPHP,5000);`
- If return value `!= 0`, do your thing.
- You could display a waiting icon as long as return value `!= 0`

Comment: This is simple *polling*, which is both wasteful of bandwidth and not 'instant', since the notification is delivered up to [poll frequency] seconds later.

Comment: True but I dont see how you could keep a PHP script running indefinitely until something new arrives. That would be even more wastful, and it will also timeout etc etc. In my opinion, 'instant' is almost always a variant of polling, but maybe im just ignorant.

Comment: You can do socket connections in PHP, and it looks like several people have [taken a shot at implementing a WebSocket server](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+websockets) in PHP (although many of those implement outdated versions of the protocol).

Comment: That's beautiful, but my guess is, that if TS is capable of implementing that, he wouldn't be asking the question. But maybe he's a PHP guru who just never heard of the concept.